# Calculating gas volume in a gas-liquid system/pressurized vessel

Tags: chemical-engineering, gas, process-engineering, compressed-gases, liquid

There is water in a tank and the tank is connected to a piece of piping that has a volume of 2.5L.

The headspace above the water is pressurised by using air, to a pressure of 3 bar (a).

What happens to the volume of gas in the piping? Is it compressed because the pressure increased to 3 bar, or does the additional gas molecules fill up the same space (and hence pressure increases through PV=nRT with no change in volume?)

[image]

*Updated Image and details*
Problem was previously simplified. The below is the actual setup. The purpose of this rig is to transfer water from the pressurised vessel to the upper tank where it is sprayed via V3. Under normal operation, the 2.5L transfer pipe is attached to both tanks, pressurised vessel is brought to 3 bar pressure, and then V1 and V2 (bleed valve) are opened to fill the 2.5L line with water. The purpose of V2 is a bleed valve, to fill the transfer solution line with liquid prior to spraying via V3. After priming, V2 is closed and V3 opened for spraying. However, this time round, a sudden surge of ~1.2kg was recorded when V3 was opened, which implies that the priming step may not have been conducted. The question is can we confirm what actually happened via doing some calculations? This is a root cause investigation.
[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the pipe is closed at the far right end somehow? In the first picture, water should be filling into the pipe since there is nothing stopping the water from going into it.

Comment: Yes that’s right. The far right end of the pipe is closed. The question is what happens to the gas volume on the far right  when you introduce gas at the other end and pressurise to 3 bar? And can the new volume of the far right void be calculated (that is, if it changes).

Comment: so how high is the tank? as the mass of the water needs to be accounted for.

Comment: I don’t have the height of the tank right now, you can assume a value for the purpose of demonstration - thanks

Comment: I assumed you meant the liquid height. The tank bottom is at the same height as the pipe.

Comment: If the pipe end that is attached to the tank is open while the tank is filled to the state shown in the first picture, the pipe will also be fully filled with water and the only space that will have air is the top of the tank.

Comment: Thanks that’s a good point - the pipe extends vertically, please see updated image in the question.

Comment: The questions is what happens to the gas volume to the far right when the pressure is raised to 3 bar(a) on the far left by using compressed air. And can this volume be predicted.

Comment: Well pressure created by a column of water is based on density * gravity * height, but many sites will have told you that. What seems to change is the question - define the question clearly so we don't have late additions. What is the height of the water in the tank?

Comment: Thanks you have a point, I’m going to confirm the setup and liquid height and come back.

Comment: I have updated the image with the correct setup. The liquid height in the pressurised vessel is 0.22 m.

Comment: I understand this is now confusing, so I have posted this as a new question: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/45619/34484